# Change data context of template property

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, dependency-properties

I have a data template property on a control which I would like to wrap to change the behavior a bit.

That template property should be exposed to the user(developer) of my control but I want to change the data context, because the data context I would like to pass the user is somewhere within the visual tree and I don't want the user to navigate there every time. So in the end the binding path is just a bit simplyfied for the user (developer) of the `BaseControl`

**XAML in control wrapper**

```
<BaseControl SomeTemplate="{Binding MyTemplate}" />
```

**Code behind in control wrapper**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "MyTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(BaseControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(DataTemplate)));

public DataTemplate MyTemplate { get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(MyTemplateProperty ); } set { SetValue(MyTemplateProperty , value); } }
```

**Usage of control wrapper**

```
<BaseControl>
  <BaseControl.MyTemplateProperty>
    <!-- desired -->
    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
    <!-- actual -->
    <!-- the data context of "OtherProperty" should be exposed to the user -->
    <Label Content="{Binding DataContext.SomeProperty.OtherProperty.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=SomeType}}" />
  </BaseControl.MyTemplateProperty>
</BaseControl>
```

Comment: You change the `DataContext` of a control by setting the `DataContext` property of it. Your issue is unclear.

Comment: I have some complex binding path within my control wrapper and I want that path to be simplyfied for the user of that wrapper template

Comment: By "user" I guess you mean the developer. That's now how it works. A control inherits a DataContext and if you want some other DataContext, you will have to set it. This is what you would expect as a WPF and XAML developer. Trying to "simplify" or modify fundamental things such as this only makes your control more complex and harder to use.